# CakePHP - add custom SQL to a Query object

Tags: orm, cakephp-3.0

I'm using CakePHP 3.5.13 to build an application which has 4 separate databases.

The main database (Datasource `default` in `config/app.php`) for the application has been baked. It was a legacy database, and the naming conventions are not written according to the way CakePHP specifies. Nonetheless it works, after going through the Models and editing things.

In a controller I have the following:

```
$substances = TableRegistry::get('Substances');

$query = $substances->find()->limit(250)->offset(0);

$query->select(['id', 'app_id', 'name']);

$query->contain([
'Cas' => [
        'sort' => ['Cas.id' => 'ASC']
    ]
]);

$query->contain([
'Ecs' => [
        'sort' => ['Ecs.id' => 'ASC']
    ]
]);
```

If I `var_dump($query)` I get an SQL string as follows:

```
SELECT Substances.id AS `Substances__id`, 
    Substances.app_id AS `Substances__app_id`, 
    Substances.name AS `Substances__name` 
FROM substances Substances LIMIT 250 OFFSET 0
```

I need to modify this so the query contains an `INNER JOIN` to a table which is stored in one of the **other** databases (Datasource `sdb5_tmpdata` in `config/app.php`). The SQL I need is as follows:

```
SELECT Substances.id AS `Substances__id`, 
    Substances.app_id AS `Substances__app_id`, 
    Substances.name AS `Substances__name`, 
    Substances.date AS `Substances__date` 
FROM substances Substances 
INNER JOIN `sdb5_tmpdata`.`searching_1745` AS tf 
ON tf.id = Substances.id LIMIT 250 OFFSET 0;
```

The difference between the above query and original is the following SQL:

```
INNER JOIN `sdb5_tmpdata`.`searching_1745` AS tf 
ON tf.id = Substances.id
```

I don't have a corresponding Model for the table `'searching_1745'` because these tables are dynamically created (and later dropped) on a database which holds "temporary" user data.

Is it possible to modify the query object, `$query`, such that I can introduce the custom SQL that does the `inner join`?

I have tried `$query = $query->newExpr()->add('INNER JOIN 'sdb5_tmpdata'.'searching_1745' AS tf ON tf.id = Substances.id');` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the query builder let you build the query as you like it. It does not matter if you don't have a Table Object for that table

```
$query->join([
    'tf ' => [
        'table' => 'sdb5_tmpdata.searching_1745',
        'type' => 'INNER',
        'conditions' => 'tf.id = Substances.id',
    ]);
```

see [**here**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#adding-joins)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can modify the query object, but tou can always write your own custom queries:

```
use Cake\Datasource\ConnectionManager;

$conn = ConnectionManager::get('default');
$query = $conn->query('query goes here');
```

for more info, read: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html#executing-queries

Comment: I understand you can write your own queries, but this isn't what I'm asking. I **want to use the ORM** to produce a query - **but then modify that query** by introducing a portion of my own SQL. If you re-read the question you'll see that all of the query can be generated through the ORM, it's the last bit which uses the `inner join` that needs to be written as custom SQL. So it's a combination of ORM, and a custom query.